# Missing bracket bug in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following script snippet:

```
if (2 -eq 2)
 {
    write-host "1"

    if (2 -eq 2)
    { 
        write-host "here"
        if (2 -eq 2)
        {                                                                                                                                                                                        {
            write-host "here3"
        }
        else 
        {
            write-host "here4"
         }
    }
     else
     {
         write-host "here5"
     }


 }
```

When I run it I got the following error:

> Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.

I don't get the problem , all the brackets are opened and closed correctly.
Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an extra opening curly bracket on line 9 (very far to the right of this line, not visible above without scrolling).

[image]